# Фоновая музыка в приложении  - MediaPlayer

Tags: mediaplayer, android

Добрый день,

У меня есть активити, в которой создаю объект MediaPlayer, запускаю музыку. Все работает как надо, кроме одного НО: при входящем звонке музыка продолжает играть поверх разговора.

вот код инициализации MediaPlayer:

```
mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sondtrack_elka);
mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
mediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
```

Пытался найти ответ поиском на свой вопрос, но не получилось.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

в `onPause()` надо стопать музыку.

```
mediaPlayer.release();
```

в `onResume()` по новой запускать

Comment: только наверное не release(), а stop() или pause(). а при Activity.onDestroy() уже освобождаем все ресурсы.

Спасибо за идею.